# How can we efficiently push data from csv file to dynamodb without using aws pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Considering the fact that there is no data pipeline available in Singapore region, are there any alternatives available to efficiently push csv data to dynamodb?

Answer (score 1):

If it was me, I would setup an s3 event notification on a bucket that fires a lambda function each time a CSV file was dropped into it.

The Notification would let Lambda know that a new file was available and a lambda function would be responsible for loading the data into dynamodb.

This would work better (because of the limits of lambda) if the CSV files were not huge, so they could be processed in a reasonable amount of time, and the bonus is the only worked that would need to be done once it was working would be to simply drop the new files into the right bucket - no server required.

Here is a github repository that has a CSV->Dynamodb loader written in java - it might help get you started.

Comment: Is the link to the github repo no longer available?